# Validate of email contains other field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, format

I need validate that user's email contains the value of it's association:

```
class Company << ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :users
end

class User << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  validate :email, presence: true
end
```

I need that before an user is saved, its email contents its company's name, for example.

if company's name is: `fedex`, the user's email has to be: `example@fedex.com`

I am using Rails 5.0

**Update:**

As *mrlew* said, I write the validator as methods, but besides this I wrote it at `app/validator` as follows:

```
#User model
class User << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  validate :email, presence: true
  validates_with UserEmailValidator
end

#Validator
# app/validator/user_email_validator.rb

class UserEmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    unless record.email =~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@#{record.company.name}\z/i
      record.errors[:email] << "invalid email"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try this one `validates_format_of :email, :with => =/^[\w\d]+@self.company.name+(.[\w\d]+)+$/` hope it will work

Comment: interpolating `self.company.name` this error ir shown `method_missing': undefined method 'company' for User (call 'User.c
onnection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom validator method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators). Something like this:

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    validate :email, presence: true
    validate :valid_company_email

    private

    def valid_company_email
        unless self.email.match(/\S+@#{self.company.name}\.com/)
            errors.add(:email, :invalid) #or replace :invalid with a custom message
        end
    end

end
```

Some considerations:

- All domains must be `.com`, like you described.
- Before the `@`: accepts everything except whitespace. It's difficult to construct a email regex (checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/3889043)), but it's up to you.

Comment: It works! and additionally I move the validator to `app/validators`. Thanks.